# CSS Effect shrink from small to bigger

Tags: html, css

i really want to know how this effect is created.

check this video, only 12 secs.

https://youtu.be/cJqU8jW0xsg

i try with :

```
.zoom {transform:scale(0.1); }
.zoom:hover {transform:scale(2); }
```

how to make it start from (top-left) and will end at (bottom-right) just like that in the video?

thanks in advance..

Comment: typically you'd shrink from bigger to small! you'd grow from small to bigger :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is the transform-origin property.

Here's an example.
http://codepen.io/dropkick/pen/YqKzdG/

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<button>click me</button>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  background: #0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  transform:scale(0.1);
}

.box-scale {
  transform:scale(1.0);
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

JS

```
$('.scale').click(function () {    
  $('.box').toggleClass('box-scale');
});
```

Comment: wow! this is awesome! so fabolus! thanks DROPKICK you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

You need transform-origin! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Setting the origin sets the start point for the transition. It'll grow out from there.